# Matlab: Cannot compile mex with openmp (undefined reference)

Tags: matlab, openmp, mex

When compiling some C++ code in Matlab 2016b using:

```
mex CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -std=c++11 -fopenmp" CXXOPTIMFLAGS='\$CXXOPTIMFLAGS -Ofast -DNDEBUG mexMyFunction.cpp
```

I got the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04, g++ version: 5.4.0.

If I remove `-fopenmp` from the above command then it worked fine. Compiling directly with g++ (without mex) also worked.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I don't know how `mex` works, but  you also have to add `-fopenmp` to the linking step.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks a lot! I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

The the following linking flags were missing:

```
LDOPTIMFLAGS="$LDOPTIMFLAGS -fopenmp -O2" -lgomp
```

Complete command:

```
mex CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -std=c++11 -fopenmp" CXXOPTIMFLAGS='\$CXXOPTIMFLAGS -Ofast -DNDEBUG' LDOPTIMFLAGS="$LDOPTIMFLAGS -fopenmp -O2" -lgomp -I"/home/khue/Libs/Eigen" mexMyFunction.cpp
```

Thanks to @Zulan for his suggestion.